# How to make this pipe communication non-blocking?

Tags: nonblocking, fifo, nim-lang

I've created 2 small programs to test inter-program communication.  It works as expected, but I want to make it non-blocking.

Like it is now if either the server (main) program or the client is stopped or crashes, the other hangs.  Some timeout mechanism?  How can I implement that?

The scheme is always request-reply

- Server sends 'request' or data to the client (let's say "What's the weather in Paris ?" or "INITIALIZED?")
- The client sends 'reply' back to the server (i.e. "Raining cats and dogs", "YES")

These are the 2 programs (based on code from Offensive Nim)

```
# main program (server sending requests)
import winim

const
  BUFLEN = 100

var pipe: HANDLE = CreateNamedPipe(
    r"\\.\pipe\pipetest",
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
    PIPE_TYPE_BYTE,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    NULL
)

var
  msgIn: string


proc bufferToString(buffer: array[BUFLEN, char]): string =
  var
    str: string = ""
  block conv:
    for c in 0..(BUFLEN-1):
      if buffer[c] != '\0':
        str.add($buffer[c])
      else:
         break conv
  return str


proc testToFromPipe() =
  var
    buffer: array[BUFLEN, char]
    text: string
    bytesRead: DWORD
  if not bool(pipe) or pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
      echo "[X] Server pipe creation failed"
      quit(1)
  
  # send 'question' to client
  try:
      echo "[*] Waiting for client(s)"
      var result: BOOL = ConnectNamedPipe(pipe, NULL)
      echo "[*] Client connected"
  
      var data: cstring = "*** Hello from the pipe server ***"
      var bytesWritten: DWORD
      WriteFile(
          pipe,
          data,
          (DWORD) data.len,
          addr bytesWritten,
          NULL
      )
      echo "[*] bytes written: ", bytesWritten
  except:
    echo "Sending to client did not work :-("
  
  # get 'reply' from client
  try:
      var result: BOOL = ReadFile(
          pipe,
          addr buffer,
          (DWORD)buffer.len,
          addr bytesRead,
          NULL
      )
      echo "[*] bytes read: ", bytesRead
      msgIn = bufferToString(buffer)  
      echo (msgIn, " (len = ", msgIn.len, " )")  
      # echo repr(buffer)
  except:
    echo "Receiving from server did not work :-("
  
  CloseHandle(pipe)

testToFromPipe()
```

```
# client program (getting requests, sending replies)
import winim


const
  BUFLEN = 100

var pipe: HANDLE = CreateFile(
    r"\\.\pipe\pipetest",
    GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    0
)

var
  msgIn: string


proc bufferToString(buffer: array[BUFLEN, char]): string =
  var
    str: string = ""
  block conv:
    for c in 0..(BUFLEN-1):
      if buffer[c] != '\0':
        str.add($buffer[c])
      else:
         break conv
  return str
     

proc testFromToPipe() =
  var
      buffer: array[BUFLEN, char]
      text: string
      bytesRead: DWORD
      data: cstring = "*** OK received, client is replying ***"
      bytesWritten: DWORD
  if bool(pipe):
    echo "[*] Connected to server"
    
    # test 1 : receive something from server
    try:
        var result: BOOL = ReadFile(
            pipe,
            addr buffer,
            (DWORD)buffer.len,
            addr bytesRead,
            NULL
        )
        echo "[*] bytes read: ", bytesRead
        msgIn = bufferToString(buffer)  
        echo (msgIn, " (len = ", msgIn.len, " )")  
        echo repr(buffer)
    except:
      echo "Receiving from server did not work :-("
    # test 2 : send (reply) something to server
    try:
      WriteFile(
          pipe,
          data,
          (DWORD) data.len,
          addr bytesWritten,
          NULL
      )
      echo "[*] bytes written: ", bytesWritten
    except:
      echo "Replying to server did not work :-("
    CloseHandle(pipe)
    
testFromToPipe()
```

I've been looking into options.  Async may be a way to go (standard Nim, I've looked at chronos but that may be more than needed).  Threading would solve the blocking of the main loop, but not the indefinite waiting in the thread if there's no reply.  The requests would just stack up I guess.